# How do you keep the backspace key from triggering onkeyup event?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have an `onkeyup` event for a text box that will not be triggered when pressing the backspace key? I mean, it will still delete the text but won't trigger an alert when pressed.

Edit: Sorry, I should have provided more information. I have a function with an alert that goes off when the wrong number is input in a text field.
It works, but when I go to delete the wrong number to enter a new one, hitting backspace causes the alert to appear.

Comment: after keyup..check input is not backspace by `e.keycode` or `e.which`

Comment: why would backspace trigger an alert?

Comment: There is not information provided to answer this question. By default a backspace does not trigger an alert.

Comment: You are right, my apologies. I have edited my question to provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onKeyUp function you can check the keycode to see if if the key was a backspace or not. The backspace keycode is 8. If its a backspace, then do nothing. Else, execute the rest of your code.

```
if (event.keycode === 8) {
  return;
}

execute rest of your code
```